# Project Management chat room renamed to "The Scrum Room"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

I renamed our site's chat room to [The Scrum Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/the-scrum-room), which seems more appropriate, not only for our site's topic, but also because of the way we've been using the room.

Our community doesn't consist of people who are here to socialize. Instead, it  consists of people looking to answer questions. Thus, the chat room isn't a constant stream of incoming messages containing cat photos and other off-topic material.

Since most of us aren't in the chat room at the same time, we've mostly used it as a way to pass messages back and forth. For instance, I'll post a note in there about how I've cleaned up a tag on our site, while [CodeGnome](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/4271/codegnome) might post that he noticed there's some questions on [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) that would be a good fit for our site. [Aziz Shaikh](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/1615/aziz-shaikh) has popped in to let us know about a bug he found on the site.

It's almost like we've used the room for a distributed, daily stand up, where people would simply drop in and briefly say what they're working on, or bring up anything of interest, and then leave.

I'm hoping the name change encourages you to drop in occasionally, as there is oftentimes good information there, even if you just read.

---

**UPDATE:** Based on the feedback, I went ahead and changed the name to [The PMSE Notice Board](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/380/the-pmse-notice-board?tab=general). Definitely drop by to check it out.

*(Pro-tip: If you don't want to actually join the room, you can "eavesdrop" via the [room's transcript url](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/380))*

Comment: Thanks for calling attention to this. I think Scrum room get's more to the point but I gotta say, I think CodeGnome nailed it with "The PMSE Notice Board."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

I'd like to see the name changed to "The PMSE Notice Board."

### Reasoning

I'd like to see the room name be less framework-specific, as not everyone is a Scrum practitioner. Additionally, we've had some [meta discussion](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/584/4271) about the site already being too focused on software-development practices.

While you can't please everyone, I think "The Scrum Room" sends the wrong message about the use of the room and what's welcome there. As [suggested](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12550083#12550083) in the chat room:

> Currently, the room description reads "A place to drop a quick note about the site, as well as general discussion for pm.stackexchange.com." The PMSE Notice Board would seem to summarize that pretty well, and the connotations of a bulletin-board system wouldn't preclude its use as a chat room.